# Pushing two floats together inside a div

Tags: css, css-float, margin, padding

Is this how it would be written, to push two floats together?

https://jsfiddle.net/ocjs81Lf/5/

```
.container-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 310px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.container-left-video {
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}

.container-right-video {
  float: right;
}
```

Margin would work here also.

https://jsfiddle.net/jc90fpzw/2/

```
.container-left-video {
  float: left;
  margin-left:20px;
}

.container-right-video {
  float: right;
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is a correct way to float two containers in one parent container but when you use float you need to clear them or it will overflow and ruin your design. You can add this clearfix class on container-top because it is parent of the div which are floating.

```
.clearfix::after {
   display: block;
   content: "";
    clear: both;
}
```